# Word не открывает файл, на котором стоит пароль

Tags: ms-word

Прошу срочной помощи! У меня был Word файл с паролем, но в один момент при его открытии стала вылезать ошибка
[image: ошибка Word]

Я уже испробовал разные способы. Например, в свойствах я его разблокировал, но это не помогло. Так же не помогло рысканье в настройках - раздел "Защищенный просмотр" отсутствует.

[image: нет раздела]

Файл был очень большим (содержал более 70 тысяч слов и 110 страниц).

Comment: Все делали по [инструкции](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/topic/устранение-проблемы-ошибка-при-попытке-открытия-файла-в-word-2007-2010-статья-из-цикла-проблемы-с-простым-решением-0903bb9b-d8e4-aabd-0364-f832d26ecff7)?

Comment: Да, перед тем, как писать сюда, я сделал все указанное в инструкции.